# Cannout set selected item jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm taking values from the url using the following function.

```
function getParameterByName( name ) //courtesy Artem
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

The url is as following.

```
http://localhost:9157/layout?oc=ARES&sn=Charitha&on=Araliya%20Restaurant.
```

This is the code where I try to set the element to be selected.

```
var oc = getParameterByName('oc');
$("#" + oc).prop("selected", true);
```

No matter how I checked using firebug and other debugging tools, the element doesn't get selected! is there anything that I'm doing wrong here! I checked whether the value from the getParameterByName() method returns correct. The values are correct! bt it doesn't work.

Comment: If the value is correct, I supposed you tried with the hardcoded selector too, so why mention getParameterByName if you know this isn't the problem ? You'd better tell us what is the element you try to select.

Comment: Try this function, it's smaller and it returns and object with all the url parameters so you can just do `GET(window.location).oc`. Here's the code https://gist.github.com/elclanrs/5696965

Comment: maybe your trying this on a checkbox? from what ive seen, `selected` only works on radio button, option etc

Comment: I found out the error! I load the select element dynamically using an AJAX call! And I've run this code before initializing the select element!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
$("#my-Select option[text=" + oc +"]").attr("selected","selected") ;
```